# Subset construction of a DFA from NFA

Tags: dfa, nfa

I am reading the book Compilers Principles, Techniques, and Tools by Alfred V.Aho. The subset construction of a DFA from an NFA has the following operations on NFA states

```
e-closure(s)| Set of NFA states reachable from NFA state s on e-transations alone  
e-closure(T)| Set of NFA states reachable from some NFA state s in set T on e-transation alone; =**U**s in T e-closure(s)  
move(T,a)   | Set of NFA states to which there is a transition on input symbol **a** from some state s in T
```

The following is an NFA accepting `(a|b)*abb` 
[image: NFA N for <code>(a|b)*abb</code>]

And the Transition table Dtran for DFA D is
[image: Transition Table]
The problem I have is I am not able to understand how we are getting NFA States  for DFA states  B C D and E
When marking DFA state A. Among the states in NFA `{0,1,2,4,7}` only `2` and `7` has transition to `a`, `move(A,a) ={3,8}`and `e-closure({3,8}) ={1,2,3,4,6,7,8}`.
`My problem is how do we end up with` `{1,2,3,4,6,7,8}` and the NFA states that follows.

Comment: Thank you for the edit @Martin Liversage

Answer (score 0):

You should also incorporate e-transitions *after* a transition. So when looking at the `move(A,a)={3,8}` you should add the states `{6,7,1,2,4}` as these are all reachable from the state 2 with `move(A,a)={3,8}` with 1 or more e-transitions.

I didn't check, but I assume the other states can be constructed similarily.